# adding fields from vendor bill in NetSuite into e-mail sent with docusign

Tags: netsuite, vendor

We want to use the fields from the vendor bill to populate the e-mail or a PDF to send with other documents from NetSuite for DocuSign

Anyone setup a form adding fields from vendor bill in NetSuite into e-mail to be sent with docusign?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to construct an email template
Documents > Templates > Email > New
select "CRMSDK - Deprecated" this allows you to input the fields into your template.
fill out the information at the top; enter in the subject
then select "Text Editor" 
type the email as desired and where you want to insert a Netsuite Field use "field Type" such as "Vendor" than use the "Insert Field" and select the field you want to insert.
After you complete the email, save and default it template to use when emailed for your Vendor Bills.